Prevent JetBrains Rider from removing dependency configuration
I have a C# project with dependencies.
I've configured the dependencies insdie the .csproj with Private set to False to prevent the packages from being copied to the build directory.
Now when I use the NuGet package manager from JetBrains Rider to upgrade a package it removes the Private element.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?
Example - Upgrading Apache.NMS from Version 2.0.0 to 2.1.0:
Before:
  <Reference Include="Apache.NMS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82756feee3957618, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Apache.NMS.2.0.0\lib\net40\Apache.NMS.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>False</Private>
  </Reference>

After:
  <Reference Include="Apache.NMS, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82756feee3957618, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Apache.NMS.2.1.0\lib\net40\Apache.NMS.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>


Would you mind sharing a full-screen IDE screenshot with visible .csproj content and NuGet tool window where you are at the moment before pressing "Upgrade"?
Also, what is the TargetFramework for your project, and do you have reasons not to use  instead of ?
